# Optimize recursive query using exclusion list

Tags: t-sql, variables, optimization, while-loop, temp-tables

I'm trying to optimizes a recursive query for speed. The full query runs for 15 minutes.
The part I'm trying to optimize takes ~3.5min to execute, and the same logic is used twice in the query.

Description:

```
Table Ret contains over 300K rows with 30 columns (Daily snapshot)
Table Ret_Wh is the werehouse for Ret with over 5million rows (Snapshot history, 90days)
```

datadate - the day the info was recorded (like 10-01-2012)

statusA - a status like (Red, Blue) that an account can have.

statusB - a different status like (Large, Small) that an account can have.

*Statuses can change day to day.*

old - an integer age on the account. Age can be increased/decreased if there is a payment on the account. Otherwise incerase by 1 with each day.

account - the account number, and primary key of a row.

*In Ret the account is unique.*
*In RetWh account is unique per datadate.*

money - dollars in the account
**Both Ret and Ret_Wh have the columns listed above**

Query Goal: Select all accounts from Ret_Wh that had an age in a certain range, at ANY time during he month, and had a specific status while in that range.
Then select from those results, matching accounts in Ret, with a specific age "today", no matter their status.

My Goal: Do this in a way that doesn't take 3.5 minutes

Pseudo_Code:

```
@sdt='2012-10-01' -- or the beginning of any month
@dt = getdate()

create table #temp (account char(20))
create table #result (account char(20), money money)


while @sdt < @dt
BEGIN

insert into #temp
select
    A.account

from Ret_Wh as A
where a.datadate = @sdt
    and a.statusA = 'Red'
    and a.statusB = 'Large'
    and a.old between 61 and 80

set @sdt=(add 1 day to @sdt)

END
------

select distinct
    b.account
    ,b.money

into #result
from #temp as A
join (Select account, money from Ret where old = 81) as B
  on A.account=B.account
```

I want to create a distinct list of accounts in Ret_Wh (call it #shrinking_list). Then, in the while, I join Ret_Wh to #shrkining_list. At the end of the while, I delete one account from #shrinking_list. Then the while iterrates, with a smaller list joined to Ret_Wh, thereby speeding up the query as @sdt increases by 1 day. However, I don't know how to pass the exact same account number selected, to an external variable in the while, so that I can delete it from the #shrinking_list.

Any ideas on that, or how to speed this up in general?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John. I didn't know that about the tags. Though a search brings up titles, and titles are much more contextual, versus disjoint tags - and there are limits on the number of tags.

Comment: The top tag is included in the title for SEO purposes. I'm not making an arbitrary suggestion. This has been very well thought out here.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a cursor to get dates from @sdt to @dt one at a time?

```
select distinct b.account, b.money
from Ret as B
join Ret_Wh as A 
  on A.account = B.account
 and a.datadate >= @sdt 
 and a.datadate <  @dt
 and a.statusA = 'Red'
 and a.statusB = 'Large'
 and a.old between 61 and 80
where b.old = 81
```

Comment: The cursor help look into the data werehouse 1 day at a time, to only consider the criteria on an account on that specific day. Thanks for your help. When I looked at this, I thought ther'd be an issue joining on the accounts since in A were looking at one range of "old" and be we're looking at another. However, this works just fine!

Comment: I inherited this code, and it's strange how even the last guy who worked on it didn't see it this way, though he's kind of helped me revisit it a bit. This is blazing fast! 8 seconds versus 1:55 in the older version. Thanks again

Comment: So then like how did this not get a check for the correct answer?   But you were still joining on multiple days.  With the cursor you were  evaluating a.statusA = 'Red' and a.statusB = 'Large' and a.old between 61 and 80 multiple times rather than once.